# Save textbox1.text to a variable on button click asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

```
  <asp:TextBox  ID="TextBox2" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="415px" Height="50px" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>


   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Save Changes" />
```

I'm attempting to save the data as such:
 protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
      Session["data"] = TextBox2.Text;           

    }
```

And retrieving:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             string temp = (string)Session["data"];
       }
```

When i print the string though, I am receiving a white space. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Put a breakpoint anywhere in Button1_Click to make sure it is being fired. Then put one after temp to see if temp is being set.

Comment: tried that, and both functions are firing off. thanks for the answwer

Answer (score 0):

In order to store data in Sesstion try something like:

```
protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Add("data", TextBox2.Text);
}
```

And no other changes in the retriving part.

As a usage I noticed that when focus is set to text box, the typing cursor is active in text box, the break point in the button's event handler is not hit when pressing the button, so this might be your non functional case.

To get this working after you finish typing into the text box, hit for instance the TAB key and then click on the button and the value from text box is retrived in button's click event handler.

Comment: im still getting a blank value returned. thanks for the attempt. do you have any other ideas?

Comment: That is quite strange... both ways of setting the value from text box in Session seems to be ok , even if I would use the way that I posted in the answer. Did you checked are you debugging the running website, is the break point hit when  trying to set the temp variable ?

Comment: yeah, it does hit the break point. its as if the clicking of the button sets the Session variable to " "....

Comment: I was using Firefox on my pc and it was working as expected... what browser are you using ?

Comment: As a usage I noticed that when focus is set to text box, the typing cursor is active in text box, the break point in the button's event handler is not hit when pressing the button, so this might be your non functional case. To get this working after you finish typing into the text box hit for instance the TAB key and then click on the button and see if the value from text box is retrived in button's click event handler. This should work.

Comment: Tried those suggestions but nothing. I eventually started from scratch and it seems to work now. Thanks for all of your help